# Can I pass a session value to variable and then save it to another guid type variable

Tags: asp.net, session, guid

```
Profile p = new Profile();

var user = Session["UserId"];

p.UserId = user ;
```

After compiling this code I am getting the error:

> can not implicitly convert object type to system.guid

Comment: Instead of `var user`, try `Guid user` and observe the compiler error. Or the other way around: what does C# think that the type of "user" is?

Comment: Did you try checking the type for both `user` & `p.UserId`?